# Convert a byte array from one encoding to another java

Tags: java, c#, .net, byte, charset

hi guys i should convert this code to C# in Java. Could you give me a hand?

```
private static String ConvertStringToHexStringByteArray(String input) {
        Encoding ebcdic = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037");
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, ebcdic, utfBytes);
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(isoBytes.length * 2);
        foreach( byte b in isoBytes)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();

    }
```

I tried to convert it to java like this. But the result is different:

```
private static String ConvertStringToHexStringByteArray(String input) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        byte[] isoBytes = input.getBytes("IBM037");
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(isoBytes.length * 2);

        for (byte b : isoBytes) {
            hex.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return hex.toString();

    }

input = "X1GRUPPO 00000000726272772"
expected = "e7f1c7d9e4d7d7d64040404040f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f1f6f7f3f5f3f5f5f2"
result = "e7f1c7d9e4d7d7d640f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f7f2f6f2f7f2f7f7f2"
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Step one open a java IDE, step 2 write java code, step 3 when you have a problem paste your java code, and your actual issue

Comment: Do not "convert" code. You write down what it _does_ and then you do not look at the original code any more and you implement these requirements in the other language.

Comment: I entered my Java conversion

Comment: What is the point of using EBCDIC?  Why not just `input.getBytes("UTF-8")` or `input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works but you are comparing the output for two different input strings.

When you write `expected` and `result` side by side:

```
e7f1c7d9e4d7d7d64040404040f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f1f6f7f3f5f3f5f5f2
e7f1c7d9e4d7d7d640f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f7f2f6f2f7f2f7f7f2
```

you will notice that both start with the same sequence (`e7f1c7d9e4d7d7d6`) which seems to come from a common beginning `X1GRUPPO`

But then the two outputs differ:

```
4040404040f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f1f6f7f3f5f3f5f5f2
40f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f7f2f6f2f7f2f7f7f2
```

Reasoning from the input that you provided, the remainder of first input string starts with 5 spaces followed by `"00000000167353552"`

This means the complete input for the C# code was `"X1GRUPPO     00000000167353552"`, which is not the same input that you provided to the Java code and then clearly the output cannot match.

Comment: you're right, I got the input wrong. thanks a lot